# Email reply to multiple email addresses not working

Tags: php

I want that email reply in php should be received at multiple email address. But it is not working for me. I have tried different ways but none of these working for me.
I am trying this header but it is only replying to the last email address.

```
$to = "recipientemail@address.com"; 
$subject = "my email subject";
$message = "my email message";
$headers = array();
$headers []= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers []= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers []= "Reply-To:  <" . $EmailAddress1 . "> <" . $EmailAddressss2 . ">" . "\r\n" ;
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I have tried without braces as well but this one is also not working

```
$headers []= "Reply-To: 1st@address.com,2nd@address.com\r\n";
```

I do not have much idea about this so little guidance about this will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Where is the full code?

Comment: I have only issue with "Reply-To". After this i am sending email via WordPress mail function which is working perfectly. wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: Ah, you're using https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Okay i have tried this but not working.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what your problem exactly is honestly, it's hard to understand what you want or the problem that's currently occurring.

Because if you're trying to reply to multiple people, you'll have to do that in the $to variable, something like this `$to = array('1st@address.com', '2nd@address.com')` instead of doing it in the header, the header you can only change the email information like the From: Cc: and Bcc: params.

Comment: Like I said, give us the full code so we don't have to waste time talking trying to figure out exactly the occurring problem.

Comment: Okay i add full code above and hopefully you will be able to understand this now.